# How to declare an associative array in PHP using array()?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

This is giving php warning

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("videos.xml") or die("Error: Object creation 
Failed");
$videos = array();

foreach( $xml->children() as $video){
   $a= $video->Serial;
   $b=$video->URI;
   $videos[$a] = $b;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($videos);
?>
```

Illegal offset type in line 8. How to Fix it ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array.php

Comment: Flagged as very low quality.

Comment: `$files = array();` and then `$files['key'] = "value";`

Comment: @Fky Why in french?

Comment: What's `$video->Serial` holding? It should be an integer or an string to be a correct index for the array

Comment: It is a String @Piyin

Comment: Are you sure? Because then it shouldn't say it's an illegal offset. Try using `var_dump(gettype($video->Serial));` right at the beginning of the `foreach` to check it's indeed a string

Comment: @Piyin php.net/manual/en/function.array.php sorry a little bit fast copy/paste (i'm french) ;) thx

Comment: @Fky hehe Sure, no problem, I was just wondering why you got there first

Comment: Yes you are write @Piyin. It was of type SimpleXMLElement Object. I've already cast it to string. It works flawlessly now :) . Thanks

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't recall those elements being objects, thanks for clear that up :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To assign values to array with keys. You can simply write:

```
$files = array();
$files['some_key'] = 'an important value';
$files['another_key'] = 'a value';
$files['key'] = 'an non-important value';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [some_key] => an important value
    [another_key] => a value
    [key] => an non-important value
)
```

You can also just create an array by simply stating `var[array_key'] = some_value'`.

For example:

```
$another['key'] = "WOW... that's cool";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [key] => WOW... that's cool
)
```

And... enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

Really PHP is super lax with arrays

This is what you would do:

```
$files = array();
$files['key'] = "value";
```

However even something like a mix of index and associative will work:

```
<?php

$files = array();

for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){
    if($i%2 ==0){
        $files["Test".$i] = $i;
    } else {
        $files[]=$i;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Test0] => 0
    [0] => 1
    [Test2] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [Test4] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [Test6] => 6
    [3] => 7
    [Test8] => 8
    [4] => 9
)
```